# Google Cloud Scheduler client does not list App Engine Cron Jobs

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-scheduler

I'm currently [scheduling Jobs with cron.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml?authuser=2) in Google App Engine standard python3 environment.

I need to show the users the last status of one of these job.

I tried python3's [google-cloud-sheduler](https://googleapis.dev/python/cloudscheduler/latest/scheduler_v1/cloud_scheduler.html?highlight=list_jobs#google.cloud.scheduler_v1.services.cloud_scheduler.CloudSchedulerClient.list_jobs) `list_jobs` method to find out jobs scheduled using `cron.yaml` don't get listed.

**How do I retrieve last run datetime and status for these jobs?**

I could save the status somewhere from within the job, before exit, seems sort of re-inventing the wheel.

Here what I tried:

```
>>> from google.cloud import scheduler
>>> client = scheduler.CloudSchedulerClient()
>>> project_id = 'PROJECT_ID' #edited accordingly
>>> location_id = 'LOCATION_ID' #edited accordingly
>>> parent = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location_id}"
>>> client.list_jobs(parent=parent)    
[]
```

The result was an empty list even if I have 4 cron jobs in my [App Engine Cron Jobs](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudscheduler) tab.

When I added a test job under [Sheduler Jobs](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudscheduler) I got it back in the `list_jobs` response.

Comment: I don't use those command line tools, but the info is shown here https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudscheduler

Comment: @gaefan I need ani API to show status to a webapp users. My users have no access to cli -- plus cli itself does not show GAE jobs

Comment: Can you also add why google-cloud-sheduler's `list_jobs` method didn't work, i.e. the request and the response?

Comment: @FaridShumbar I added it in the question: basically the response was `[]`

Comment: Do you run this code in the App Engine? 

Per the documentation you shared, this is an async function, so perhaps you are getting an empty result because you don't `await`. Perhaps you could share the whole function that this code is executing. 
You can also try executing this code directly in the gcloud CLI to make sure it's a Python code issue and not something related to the project.

Comment: @FaridShumbar I _do_ executed it in the CLI... no async problems, believe me, simply App Engine Cron Jobs are **not** there. I honestly expected someone form [google-app-engine] shed a light here...